# undefined reference boost::program_options::abstract_variables_map::operator[]

Tags: c++, linux, boost, linker, boost-program-options

When I'm linking program_options to my shared library with:

```
g++ -L/path_to_static_boost_libs -shared -o "test.so"  ./test.o   -lboost_program_options
```

I can't load library because of undefined reference on abstract_variables_map::operator[]:

```
0009b9f8 W int const& boost::program_options::variable_value::as<int>() const
         U boost::program_options::abstract_variables_map::operator[](std::string const&) const
0009b55e W boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_any_cast> >::clone() const
```

I tried to build another program (not shared library) with program_options library linked statically and didn't get undefined reference.

Why I get undefined reference when I'm linking shared library?

Comment: Try adding `-lboost_system` as well.

Comment: post the code that goes into `test.so` so we can reproduce the behavior you see.

Comment: So, what was needed eventually?

Comment: @Nico Schlömer: I can't remember, but problem was connected with boost library version or library type (shared, static) mismatches with custom libraries, something like that. So careful and precise rebuilding and linking to my project of boost libraries helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: find out *mangled* name of the unresolved symbol (should already show up in the `dlerror()` error message).

Step 2: find out *which* of the boost libraries provides definition for that symbol:

```
nm -A /path_to_static_boost_libs/*.a | grep <mangled-symbol-name>
```

Step 3: add that library to the link line of `test.so`.

Step 4: profit.